# lowest tire pressure for a 44psi tire

Tags: tires, pressure

I want to know what it the lowest tire pressure you could put on a maximum rate 44psi tire? I have been placing 33- 34 psi on these tires for about half a year now, will it damage my tires? I'm planning to put 36psi to it to make it near the rated maximum limit.

Comment: The more important number is the psi that your car expects - check the metal plate inside the driver's side door.

Comment: I have no answer on the subject just an observation. I have been filling my tire to 32 psi which is the spec on the vehicle. The last time I filled my tire I noticed the tire is rated at 44 psi Max. I filled it to 40 PSI and started getting about 5 miles per gallon more and I don't notice a difference in the handling of the vehicle.

Comment: My tire reads 44 psi max and inside door reads 35 psi Front 33 psi Rear...Toyota Prius 2012...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tire pressure is typically determined by vehicle weight and type of tire. In other words, the 44 psi you refer to is the maximum inflation of the the tire at its maximum load rating.

You can safely inflate the tires to the maximum pressure, but it may not give you the best ride or performance. Each vehicle has a specified pressure/load rating on a placard in the door jam area. It may look something like this;

[image]

Since you've not given us information about the type of tire or the vehicle, I will say to use a pressure 10% to 15% under the maximum psi rating to get the best performance of the tire.

This is just a guess and you will have to do a little research yourself depending on the brand tire and type of vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

38psi seems perfect for a tire with a 44psi max cold.  Recommend checking between Winter and Summer.  Technically, you should check every month, but how many of us do that.  My truck which has a rated tire at 80psi cold seems to do best in the 50-60psi range.  When you start getting near 7
70-80psi, you're in for a pretty hard ride.  This also can add unnecessary stress on shocks/struts, and general suspension components.  Note:  If you tend to carry heavy loads, you may want to be slightly higher in psi, but never exceed that max cold rating and remember to check when vehicle has been idle, like overnight, and check before the sun can influence anything.

Answer (score 1):

Tire air pressure only needs to match the weight of the vehicle/area of ground surface per tire  /4tires. Yet cornering can increase inertial mass on tires and increase friction wear and life time.

So pressure is a trade off between gentle bump absorption and comfort with tire lifespan. Using the recommended pressure may optimize lifespan. But not comfort,  and number of passengers + luggage can make a difference.

Your optimal tire pressure depends on your cornering and bump absorption for speed bumps causing rim damage vs comfort of benign highway driving noise and vibrations.

Answer (score 0):

I. run 38psi when were rated at 44psi cold. when they warmed up they were at 40psi. they wore perfectly. got 64,000 out of them . the were 
little over 5yrs old

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2011 ford fusion.  Tires have 44 psi max inflation on the sidewall and the door sticker has 31 psi.  Big difference!  At 60,000 miles the tread on the outside is near the wear indicators and the tread in the middle is probably only half-way down.  When I look up why tires wear that way i find it is usually due to under-inflation.  Getting ready to get new tires and will definitely keep them close to 40 psi.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to the site. You should always set your tyre pressure according to the car's spec (i.e. the sticker on the door). The number on the tyre is the maximum, not the desired pressure.

Answer (score -1):

The door will be the original tire that came with the car, if you put original tires they call for back on when you need new ones. you probably keep the same specs , when you change tire brands and different sizes, the manufacturer will give you the specs for that tire , and safety of that tire , I always go buy the tire specs , pressure on the side wall of the tire im checking, you can allways call the tire factory that makes that brand of tire, that would be better than everybody on here just guessing.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  It looks like you might have some good info here, but it's different from what I've heard before.  Would you mind providing some references for the info you're giving?  It'll be much easier to convince others if they come from authoritative sources as well.

Answer (score -2):

Many older cars came with max 35 psi tires installed.
You won’t find ANY tire with that anymore. They start at 44 and go to 65, so putting the original 35 psi type tire pressure in one designed for 44 is dangerously under-inflating.
The 10-15% below max is a good start, then adjust down for ride comfort versus fuel economy. This will always be a trade off. If they wear on the outsides, they’re either under-inflated, or you do a lot of high-speed cornering.

Comment: I just bought a new full sized 1/2 ton pickup truck. The tag on it for tire pressures (including the full sized spare) is 35psi. This, to my knowledge, is pretty standard. If you have a good reference stating otherwise, I'd love to see it.